# Can I separate table content per year using library formattable?

Tags: r, formattable

Im using this code to create a visual table of main causes of x problem in a 4 year lapse.

```
specificRows <- subset(mainDF, select = "Cause")
Catalogue <- merge(specificRows, Catalogue, by.x = "Cause", by.y = "idCause")

Catalogue <- tabyl(Catalogue, Clasification)
Catalogue <- Catalogue[order(-Catalogue$n), ]
cat$Percentage <- round((cat$Percentage* 100), 2)

nice_table(
  Catalogue,
  highlight = TRUE,
  title = c("Table Title"),
  note = "Table Note",
)
```

I'd like to know if it is possible to create subdivisions within the table as to show main causes per each of these 4 years.

Thank you!

I haven't tried anything different, but I also haven't found solutions online or with friends who use R.

An alternative would be manually creating the tables on word or something, but I'd like to know if I can avoid that!

Comment: Hi charles, welcome to SO. It is better to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. In your case, this means doing something like running `dput(specificRows)` and adding the result to your question. Also it would be useful to see an example of your desired output. Thanks